# Save bash Data To Redis

Tags: linux, bash, redis

I am running this command from terminal.

```
adb shell top -m 5 -d 01.00 | 
     grep --line-buffered 'com.android.calculator2' > '/writeTestData.txt'
```

It gives continuous output of the process info in the text file.
I want to save this data simultaneously to `Redis`.

How can that be done? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the following command solves your problem.

```
adb shell top -m 5 -d 01.00 | grep --line-buffered 'com.android.calculator2' \
| tee writeTestData.txt | xargs -I {} redis-cli -p 6379 set key {}
```

As you see, Rambo Ramon's solution ([tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))) is the key. Basically, tee is used in this case to send the input (which comes from adb command) to two different outputs: the first is the .txt file and the second is the input of the piped command.

[xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) gets the output of tee, line by line, and sends it as an argument to the [set](http://redis.io/commands/set) command of redis-cli tool.

6379 is the default port of Redis, you can change it according to the port(s) your server(s) are running on.

set key {} basically stores in Redis the output which comes from tee, through xargs, at the key named "key". So at a single key, it stores every time the newest value that comes from xargs.

If you want to store your content at the same key (append), you can use the [append](http://redis.io/commands/APPEND) command which has the same syntax as set. So you replace set with append, that is the only change in the command above.

I've tested that using a similar command to the one you need (that gives continuous output) and it works fine:

Test command:

```
top | grep --line-buffered Cpu | tee file.txt | xargs -I {} redis-cli -p \  
6900 set key {}
```

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct, please? I am really glad that I managed to solve your problem.

Comment: Done. I am curious to know another thing :)
Now I am able to write all my data to the file and redis. If I want to conditionally write the data.
i.e Suppose, I want to write the data to redis only if currently the "key" is null, and if its not null, I want to wait till it becomes null and then write the data. 
To make the data key null, I have another script running which reads the data from redis, and makes it null after reading.

Comment: I don't really know if the "key" is null. Maybe you are referring to the value stored at the key named "key", because if the key is null, you can't really store something on it because it doesn't exist any more. 

In other words, if we are referring to the value that becomes null at some point (when your script finishes reading from Redis), you can simply solve that by trying to get the value of that key, with redis-cli -p 6379 get key and check the output of that command. If it's null, then you will wait in some way. Of course, it might be a bit tricky to make that happen in an oneliner.

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the value stored at that key named "key".
I need a way to first check for the value, and then save the data only if it is null. 
Anything would help, One liner not necessary :P

Comment: That adb command, as same as top, gives you continuous output that you  have to process in some way. At every clock-tick of the system, you get another value (data). At most, you can just stop the process of handling the flow, but not to stop it (the flow), or to make it wait. That means that you can stop writing to redis, while the other script reads from it, but while that operation is done, the adb command spans some output that you cannot process for moment, because you wait the reading from redis. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I will try to implement a script that solves your problem. But I can't really do that right now because I am at work. In the following hours, I will work on it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. That would be really helpful

Comment: Can you please tell me why did you unmarked my answer? I've just started to work at your script. So should I understand that my answer is not longer what you need?

Comment: I am really sorry man....I marked it as correct....I really don't know how it got changed....Have marked it as correct again....

Comment: And yes, if you can help me with the script, that'll be really great of you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `Redis` is but probbaly you can pipe the output to `tee` which can redirect it to multiple readers. Consider this example:

```
echo -e 'aaa\nccc\nbbb\naaa\nbbb' | \
    tee >(grep "aaa" | wc -l) >(grep "ccc" | wc -l) > /dev/null
```

The redirect to /dev/null is only necessary because tee also copies the output to `stdout`.